# Client-side Javascript: Showing the browser's address bar when a site hides it?

Tags: show, userscripts, address-bar, userjs

I'm trying to make a short client-side script that will run as UserJS in something like Greasemonkey. The script is to prevent sites from hiding the browser's navigation buttons. [Topic info here](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10065224/hide-address-bar-of-current-webpage-browser.aspx).

I've come up with `Window(location=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=yes);` This gives a "Read-Only" error though. All the info when I search is about web authors wanting to turn off the address bar (etc), not users wanting to turn it back on.

[Click a product on this page to see the problem](http://www.suyin.com/en/product/product-list.aspx?leftid=12&bigid=1&SID=15&keyword=Enter%20Part%20Number&x=111&y=4).